# I want to print my datagridview, but in merged table inside print preview

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

[image: My datagridview]
I have a datagridview like this, as we can see there's total amount column. I want to print the datagridview, and make sum of total column at the end of the row in merged column. what should I do to make it work?

I am expecting the result must be like this
[image: Result that I wanted]
and I had try this

```
Using f As Font = New Font(cobacoba.dgv2.Font.FontFamily, cobacoba.dgv2.Font.Size)
    Using br As New SolidBrush(Color.Black)
        'draw the header
        Dim CellLeftPos As Integer = 50
        For col = 0 To cobacoba.dgv2.ColumnCount - 1
            Dim CellValue As String = cobacoba.dgv2.Columns(col).HeaderText
            Dim CellWidth = cobacoba.dgv2.Columns(col).Width + 50

            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightGray, CellLeftPos, CellTopPos, CellWidth, CellHeight)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(CellValue, f, br, CellLeftPos + offset, CellTopPos + offset)
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, CellLeftPos, CellTopPos, CellWidth, CellHeight)

            CellLeftPos += CellWidth
        Next
        CellTopPos += CellHeight

        'draw the rows
        For Row = LastRow To cobacoba.dgv2.RowCount - 1
            CellLeftPos = 50
            CellHeight = cobacoba.dgv2.Rows(0).Height

            For Cell = 0 To cobacoba.dgv2.ColumnCount - 1
                Dim CellValue As String =     cobacoba.dgv2.Rows(Row).Cells(Cell).Value.ToString()
                Dim CellWidth = cobacoba.dgv2.Rows(Row).Cells(Cell).Size.Width + 50

                e.Graphics.DrawString(CellValue, f, br, CellLeftPos + offset, CellTopPos + offset)
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, CellLeftPos, CellTopPos, CellWidth, CellHeight)
                CellLeftPos += CellWidth
            Next

            CellTopPos += cobacoba.dgv2.Rows(Row).Cells(0).Size.Height

            If CellTopPos > e.MarginBounds.Bottom - cobacoba.dgv2.Rows(Row).Cells(0).Size.Height Then
                e.HasMorePages = True
                LastRow = Row + 1
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
    End Using
End Using
```

but the result is [image: the results that I have tried]
what should I do?

Comment: *"I want to print the datagridview"*. No you don't. What you want is to print data from the `DataGridView`. They are not the same thing. Start thinking about logic first and then write code to implement that logic. Get the data from the grid first, package it up in a form that represents what you want to print, then print that data. Those are three distinct steps so treat them that way. Work out the logic associated with each one separately and then implement that logic. You can combine them into a whole at the end. Your printing should not involve the grid at all.